# 2nd router won't connect to the internet/won't let devices connect

Tags: networking, router, dhcp, internet-connection, bridge-router

So i have two routers 1st router is my main router (Huawei HS8145C,ip is 192.168.100.1) which is connected to my ISP, then a 2nd router(Huawei hg8245h, i.p is 192.168.100.2) that i tried to become an access point i already configured it and set the LAN ip and disabling the dhcp and setting up the dhcp range, but after i save changes and i tried to connect through wifi with other device it will indicate obtaining ip address  for quite sometime then eventually, will say failed to obtain ip address, what would be the problem? i tried making access point on same network before with other routers it will work but with this new 2nd router it just wont let me connect.

Comment: Routers may function in 2 ways : bridge or router. The bridge setup is the easier : a client can see the DHCP server through the bridge and obtain useful IP address. A (level 3) router makes you need 2 ip ranges (let’s say 192.168.100.0/24 and 192.168.101.0/24), propose a DHCP for its client, assure network address translation. This is more complex but can be handled by most routers. See Lan port work mode in the manual and deselect anything, then the bridge mode will be used.

Comment: The previous advice is for the second bridge/router. The router connected to your ISP should be unchanged.

Comment: @FrédéricLoyer so the solution is i but a new 2nd router? im sorry im not really knowledgeable about this but i have tried making some old routers as a secondary router from the past.

Comment: No, use the second retour as a bridge. See the section of manual I have proposed.

Comment: @FrédéricLoyer The manual says that i can put it in bridge mode through the "WAN" section but when i go to WAN section in the GUI of the router it is blank, By the way it is a router that was provided by my previous ISP before.

Comment: You can setup a router as a (managed) "switch" in this case you only use the "yellow" plugs. In this configuration the first router is the dhcp for the WLAN. This is most probably the easiest config.

Comment: If the router has not all configuration activated, it may be hard to use it as wanted. Note that many ISP provided routers function as a router with a builtin 196.168.1.0 local network. With two chained routers which use the same address range, IP address conflicts may arrive. Try the previous comment first, but I don’t well this « managed switch » mode.